# How to remove the text after input field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, nextsibling

How can I remove the text after the input in jQuery?

**jQuery**

```
<div id="date_filter_si">
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="Y" checked=""> year
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="W" checked=""> Weekly
</div>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<div id="date_filter_si">
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="Y" checked=""> 
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="W" checked=""> 
</div>
```

```js
$( "#date_filter_si:contains('Weekly')" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to change next sibling text of element.

```
$("#date_filter_si > input")[0].nextSibling.textContent = "";
```

```js
$("#date_filter_si > input")[0].nextSibling.textContent = "";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date_filter_si">
  <input type="radio" class="date_action"> year
</div>
```

If you have multiple input and sibling text use this:

```
$("#date_filter_si > input").each(function(){
    this.nextSibling.textContent = "";
});
```

```js
$("#date_filter_si > input").each(function(){
  this.nextSibling.textContent = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date_filter_si">
  <input type="radio" class="date_action"> year
  <input type="radio" class="date_action"> week
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the text nodes (element.nodeType == 3) and then remove.

```js
$("#date_filter_si").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; 
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date_filter_si">  
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="Y" checked="" onclick="set_date_filter('Y')"> year
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="W" checked="" onclick="set_date_filter('W')"> Weekly
</div>
```

Comment: i need to remove the both week and year

Comment: @QuestionUser It will work for all text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```js
$( "#date_filter_si:contains('Weekly') input" ).each(function(){
  var el = this.nextSibling;
  if(el && el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date_filter_si">
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="Y" checked="" onclick="set_date_filter('Y')"> year
    <input type="radio" class="date_action" name="date_action" value="W" checked="" onclick="set_date_filter('W')"> Weekly
</div>
```